# Java- Read the first value from the list and store in a variable using Intellij

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, xpath

I'm facing an issue while trying to retrieve and save the first value from the web element list. I wrote a XPATH to retrieve but it is fetching the null value. Surprisingly the same xpath is working correctly from the chrome browser. So please guide me to understand where and what went wrong.
Please find the below HTML code and the XPath.

From the below list of values, I should select the first value and store in a variable. (i.e. Coffee)

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="width: 132.667px; top: 440.885px; left: 531px; display: none;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><a id="ui-id-6" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"></a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><a id="ui-id-7" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Coffee</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><a id="ui-id-8" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Tea</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item"><a id="ui-id-9" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
XPATH  (//ul[@id='ui-id-1']//li//a[@class='ui-menu-item-wrapper'])[2]
```

> I am so confused on, why this xpath is highlighting correctly in chrome browser but the same is giving null value while running from the script. Please help me to resolve the issue.

**Note:-** Before reading the value, first I'm clicking the select dropdown and then trying to read the value.

Comment: Why to cling on xpath? Better to use more direct locator `List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.className("ui-menu-item-wrapper")); String value1 = items.get(0).getText();   String value2 = items.get(1).getText();   ...`

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the elements are in the XHTML namespace, but I can't tell whether this is the case from the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ty below code

```
            WebElement ul_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("x_path_to_your_ul_tab"));
            List<WebElement> li_list = ul_element.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            WebElement first_li_element = li_list.get(0);
```

also you can iterate all li elements like below

```
            for (WebElement li : li_list ) {
                if (li.getText().equals(role)) {
                    li.click();
                }
            }
```